# why TypedArray.getIndexCount() always returns 0

Tags: android

```
<!--attrs.xml-->
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="View2">  
        <attr name="textColor" format="color"/>  
        <attr name="textSize" format="dimension"/>  
    </declare-styleable> 
</resources>
<!--styles.xml-->
<resources>
    <style name="View2">
        <item name="textColor">#ffffffff</item>
        <item name="textSize">22dip</item>
    </style>
</resources>
<!--the View2 class defined-->
public View2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);   
        TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.View2);
    final int len =array.Length();
        final int N =array.getIndexCount();//why N==0,because i initialize in styles.xml
}
<!--the callback method,like in Activity.onCreate(..)-->
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    View2 v = new View2(this,null);
}
```

I declare a styable name="View2" in attrs.xml,and then i initialize the two attrs in the styles.xml,and then i obtainStyle in TypedArray,and it's a question,why N==0,because i initialize the two attrsin styles.xml

Comment: How do you use the `View2` style?

Comment: ....
final int N =array.getIndexCount(); 
<!--Just test whether etc.R.styleable.View2_textSize gets its value of 22dip -->
int textColor = array.getColor(R.styleable.View2_textColor, 0XFF00FF00);
float textSize = array.getDimension(R.styleable.View2_textSize, 36); 
//but getDimension() returns the default value 36,not 22  
}
Look at my comments in the codes,I was doubted that how to use the parameter attrs,in the onCreate() method i passed null 

to it,if it's correct?how i should use the parameter attrs,the getIndexCount() will able to get not zero.

Comment: I would advise you to read some tutorials about custom views and styles/attributes. The constructor that you used in the `onCreate` method is usually used automatically when the view is declared in the xml layout.

Comment: thanks for your advise,i know the custom views,in custom views i can get the expected result,getIndexCount() return not zero. But i want to do some creative things,i don't define class myview extends Views{...},i want to define a class which has the same functions with android's View. the defination like this "class mysupperView extends Object...,so..

Comment: If you want to actual show that custom class it needs to extends the `View` class. Every android widget extends this superclass.

Comment: Thanks a lot! what you said is exactly right.