# How do I store a floating point number in Android resource file

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using font size percentage `0.96f` which is floating point. On different devices I might want higher font size percent. How do I store this as a resource? I suppose I could store as `95` and divide by `100` but anyway how do you store floating point numbers in resource file which might give different value depending on device resolution/size etc. just like for layout files. If you are curious about the percent its because I am reducing the size of the font by `4%` to fit a TextView onto my view. Soon there will be in `Android O` a new TextView to do the scaling but not now.

Thanks

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984969/android-float-double-resource-type

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984969/android-float-double-resource-type try this

Comment: If we stipulate that integer might be the way to go here and store it at 94 I would still like to know how to get back different integer based on device resolution from resource.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android float/double resource type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984969/android-float-double-resource-type)

Comment: Ok, so would I create multiple dimension.xml files? where do these go exactly to give me different values based on device size?

Comment: That's what I need to know!

Answer (score 0):

To get different integer based on device resolution from resource, you have to add Different values folder for different screens in res directory. For ex: 
- values
- values-small
- values-large
- values-sw600dp

Add dimens.xml in every values folder and add dimensions according to resolution.

16dp