# error NotFoundException while trying to retrieve dimension

Tags: android, android-resources

It's curiously, but I can't get dimen value, so what's wrong? Making Clean or Invalidate caches doesn't help.

**dimens.xml:**

```
<dimen name="dialog_width_percent">0.85</dimen>
```

**code:**

```
float percent = context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dialog_width_percent);
```

Got `Resources$NotFoundException`

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: Who is `context`?

Comment: @AbnerEscócio `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not suppose to use float or double as a resource type, check this link:
[Android float/double resource type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984969/android-float-double-resource-type)

Basically it explains if you want to use this type you will have to do a kind of "hack". As from the orignal post:

```
 <item name="float" type="dimen" format="float">9.52</item>
```

Referencing from java

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
getResources().getValue(R.dimen.my_float_value, typedValue, true);
float myFloatValue = typedValue.getFloat();
```

Link to android dev site that explains not being able to use float/double:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources

Comment: Glad it worked! can you set this as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

`0.85` is not a valid dimen. Use `fraction`

```
<fraction name="dialog_width_percent">0.85</fraction>

float percent = context.getResources().getFraction(R.fraction.dialog_width_percent, 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `0.85dp` as follow

```
<dimen name="dialog_width_percent">0.85dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dimensions expect `dp` use fraction instead.

`<fraction name="dialog_width_percent" type="fraction">85%</fraction>`

You can then call it in your activity like this:

`float percent = context.getFraction(R.fraction.dialog_width_percent, 1, 1);`